# consultar rutas visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Buen dia

La pregunta es la siguiente lo que pasa es que debo consultar si exite una ruta de una carpeta lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
Dim ruta As String = “C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\lmud1p40.inf_amd64_9a2338ab5b59d9ef”
    If IO.Directory.Exists(ruta) Then
        Dim a As New Form3
        a.Show()
        Me.Finalize()
    Else
        MsgBox("Usted no posee los drivers necesarios para la instalacion", 16, "Drivers")
        Close()
    End If
```

lo que pasa es que debo consultar dos rutas si existe alguna de las dos el programa continua ,como podria hacerlo ,las rutas son

```
 “C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\lmud1p40.inf_amd64_9a2338ab5b59d9ef”
 “C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\lmud1p40.inf_amd64_neutral_9a2338ab5b59d9ef”
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: con un or en el if?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar [OR](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference//operators/or-operator)

```
Dim ruta As String = “C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\lmud1p40.inf_amd64_9a2338ab5b59d9ef”

Dim rutaDos as string =  “C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\lmud1p40.inf_amd64_neutral_9a2338ab5b59d9ef”

    If IO.Directory.Exists(ruta) Or IO.Directory.Exists(rutaDos) Then
        Dim a As New Form3
        a.Show()
        Me.Finalize()
    Else
        MsgBox("Usted no posee los drivers necesarios para la instalacion", 16, "Drivers")
        Close()
    End If
```

Comment: gracias asi era ,me complique agregando mas variables sabiendo que existe el OR ,agradesco tu ayuda